# Making a list with some strings only

Tags: python-3.7

Okay so i have a string of data

`data= "DTG: 20191005/0925Z VAAC: LONDON VOLCANO: ASKJA"`

so i want to make it a dictionary like
`{DTG:'20191005/0925Z',VAAC:'LONDON',VOLCANO:'ASKJA'}`

i used `split` function to split these up and make a list but somehow i cant seem to make it

`print(data.split(":"))`

I have to make it as a list like:
`{DTG:'20191005/0925Z',VAAC:'LONDON',VOLCANO:'ASKJA'}`

Can anyone help?

ok so if u can do the above one how about data from the file 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/zg0kmh

Comment: Hi, please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, `{DTG:'20191005/0925Z',VAAC:'LONDON',VOLCANO:'ASKJA'}`
 is called a dictionary and not a list.

Now to create that dictionary, you woukd want to split the string on whitespace , rather than `:`, then you can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) alternate elements together to make a tuple of keys and values, then convert that zip to dict

Note that the below solution assumes that the each individual word is a key or a value. If you have a value or a key like `hello world`, this logic won't work, then perhaps another logic to split the string (another character instead of whitespace, or a regex split) will be more beneficial

```
data= "DTG: 20191005/0925Z VAAC: LONDON VOLCANO: ASKJA"

#Split string on whitespace
arr = data.split()

#Zip alternate elements together
arr_zip = zip(arr[::2], arr[1::2])

#Convert dict to zip and print it
dct = dict(arr_zip)
print(dct)
```

The output will be `{'DTG:': '20191005/0925Z', 'VAAC:': 'LONDON', 'VOLCANO:': 'ASKJA'}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is in exactly this format, you could use the following code:

```
data = "DTG: 20191005/0925Z VAAC: LONDON VOLCANO: ASKJA"
parts = data.split()
output = {
  'DTG': parts[1],
  'VAAC': parts[3],
  'VOLCANO': parts[5],
  }
```

However, this doesn't take into account spaces very well, if there are spaces in your data (e.g. "NEW YORK").

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict.update`:

```
data = "DTG: 20191005/0925Z VAAC: LONDON VOLCANO: ASKJA"
d = dict()
d.update(s.split(':') for s in data.replace(': ', ':').split())
```

Output:

```
{'DTG': '20191005/0925Z', 'VAAC': 'LONDON', 'VOLCANO': 'ASKJA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data= "DTG: 20191005/0925Z VAAC: LONDON VOLCANO: ASKJA"

data = data.split()
dic = {}
for d in data:
    if ":" in d:
        key = d.replace(":","")
    else:
        dic[key] = d

print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'DTG': '20191005/0925Z', 'VAAC': 'LONDON', 'VOLCANO': 'ASKJA'}
```